VS2022: "Loading symbols for ..." popup keeps coming
While working/debugging in VS2022 a popup keeps coming up for symbol loading. Letting it run (takes a few seconds) makes it disapear but after a few minutes (~10) it comes back and does the same thing again.
Clicking Cancel also makes it go away but again not for very long.
VS2022 version is now 17.9.3 (a few small updates behind). The problem started a few versions earlier.
Just My Code is enabled in options.
Can this be run in the background or disabled?
EDIT: seems to be happening a lot when debugging is stopped, but also when debugging and less when coding without the debugger/program running.

Thanks in advance.

I use to get this from time to time a while ago - I thought it was because I was using Visual Studio 2022 Preview edition, but that doesn't seem to be your case here.  The other thing I thought it may be was at some point I messed with the symbol servers in the options.   Not really sure what I ended up doing (if anything) to fix it.

Just to clarify, this happens even when you're not running your application, just working with VS? What are the assemblies (dlls) that get symbol loaded? Is it always the same one? Do you reproduce this for any other project (e.g. empty console) as well or is it just one specific project? Could you share your symbol settings? It's in Tools > Options > Debugging > Symbols.

Your issue is related to the way VS2022 loads symbols. Here are some possible solutions:

Select Delete All Breakpoints from the Debug menu.
Go to Debug -> Options -> Debugging -> Symbols, click Empty Symbol Cache and choose not to load symbols from the Microsoft symbol server or to only search for symbols in the local directory.
Go to Tools > Options > Debugging > General, disable the Just My Code option.

If this answer is not what you want, please provide a more detailed description of your requirements.
